# Trying to pull product information from webstores into my site with JS/PHP

Tags: javascript, php, curl, file-get-contents

There are several similar questions about loading remote HTML via curl or file_get_contents and such, but they fail supposedly for security reasons (x-site scripting or some such thing).

I'm all for security, but I want my users to be able to put in a URL to a product page on BestBuy, Costco, Target or whatever and have my site take a quick peek at the page and pull back title, description, and an image of said item.

They will be dropping the URL on my page. I can get the URL that they dropped pretty easily, but I can't seem to find a way to do anything with it.

Comment: What's the issue you are coming across? Can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: I need to get some content from a remote page in a different domain. I want someone to be able to give me a URL on my page and my code will go and check what product is there, what it's title is, what pic is used for it. Right now I'm using a bookmarklet that does this and it's great, but requires that they have the bookmarklet installed and then click it.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't answer your question. The issue is there's no method I've been able to find that does what I need. I can't use ajax to grab the site HTML (which would work), I can't append my JS to their page and run it, I can't just send a query to that page and they answer (without signing up for 20 or more APIs and then writing the code for each). My question is simply: is it possible to, from my website, scan the HTML of a page in another tab or iframe or whatever and return to Javascript some elements on that page based on ID or classname or whatever.